# How to make a discord bot react to a set of different words with the same set of sentences?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Right now I can make the bot to react to a single word, is it possible to make it in one piece of code to make the bot react to a different set of words with the same sentences?

For example I tried  if 'X' and 'Y' and 'Z' in message.content: and of course it didn't react but I don't know why and how can I make it possible? I have been told to use any() but I have no clue how to use it.

```
 xyz_quotes = ['QuotesX','QuotesY','QuotesZ']

    if 'X' in message.content:
        response = random.choice(xyz_quotes)
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a simple for loop:

```
xyz_quotes = ['QuotesX','QuotesY','QuotesZ']
trigger_words = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

for word in trigger_words:
    if word in message.content:
        response = random.choice(xyz_quotes)
        await message.channel.send(response)
        break
```

This iterates over a list of words that you define and then checks if those words are in the message. The `break` stops the loop once a message has been sent otherwise the bot would send multiple messages when multiple words occur in the same message.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats what I needed!